# Spark MLlib recommendation - restaurant/ item similarity - issues/improvement

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, apache-spark

### Use Case

Recommend similar items (restaurants) to diner.

### Solution:

We have used *apache spark MLlib ALS algorithm*. Values for lambda and rank has been obtained by iterating through all permutations of combinations on selected range of ranks (9-20) and lamda(0.0001-3). We have kept iterations constant (10). In the end, we evaluated the rank-lamda for which the error is minimum  for our dataset and used it .

> Note - Training set - booking matrix for time range say November
>   2015-March 2016. Test Set/Cross Validation Set - booking matrix for
>   the same diner set for time range April 2016 - May 2016. This is just
>   example, we have followed 70/30 ratio.

### Approaches followed:

*Approach 1* - 
input data consists dinerID,restaurantID,rating. rating in this case is the number of time a restaurant has been booked. 0 rating if it has not been booked.

*Approach 2 -* 
Instead of number of times a restaurant has been booked, we have rating as 1 if diner has booked a restaurant. 
Using Approach 2 as it had far less error rate.

**Considerations/Tail cutting**:

1. Only active diners and restaurants considered
2. Diner who has booked more than 1 restaurant has been considered
3. Restaurant which has been booked more than once is considered.

*Implementation:*
These 16 latent factors (rank - 16 in our case) for every restaurant/item is obtained and persisted in database. Since our dataset is not big (*~25k items*), on runtime *euclidean distance* for each is calculated and top 5 are recommended for each restaurant.

### Problem:

Restaurants are city specific and so are diners. But while building model as well as creating input matrix, city or any other explicit factor is not taken. I believe spark should be identifying a pattern and one of the factor could be city as well.
Now, out of X number of cities we operate in, 70%-80% of our business is driven from a city A. A small number from rest 2-3 cities and very few from the rest.
Recommendation for city A is very good. Also, the recommendations for other 2-3 cities seem to be decent to normal. Other cities, honestly I have not evaluated.

**Pain point:**
Since model is trained irrespective of city, I assume the 16 factor vector for each restaurant is a good metric to compare item item similarity. So, if my last booking is a restaurant abc in city A and next time I am in city B (I am new to this city btw) and looking for similar restaurants. What I have implemented is item-item for restaurant abc and restaurants in city B.
Whenever similar restaurant to any restaurant from city A(the major driver) is calculated for any other city, irrespective of which restaurant from city A has been selected, recommendations are same. However, there are slight variations if instead of city A there are comparisons between city b/c/d/e.

1. What could be the possible reasons to this?
2. Is it because of heterogeneous/skewed data?
3. Ways to improve recommendations?
4. Can we work on individual latent factors (for example if it is identified that factor2 is city, factor 3 could be cuisine, then can we manipulate??)
5. Any other way to improve or test model?

Comment: First I'll try to use a higher number of iterations. ALS is an iterative algorithm and typically 10 isn't a typical value. I use between 100 and a 150 iterations in some of my models.